# How to certificate WP8 app with HERE launcher

Tags: windows-phone-8, here-api, here-launcher

I have created an application which use [HERE Application Launchers](http://developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Lumia/#!maps-and-navigation/here-launchers.html) and my app work fine on my Nokia Lumia 720.

**My problem** is certification on marketplace I get the response like:

```
The application exhibits device specific behavior that inhibits functionality and    
features. The application's main functionality
cannot be tested on non-Nokia devices because it requires Nokia Here Drive.

-Launch the application on HTC 8X.
...
-Observe the user is prompted to install the app "Here Drive".
```

I agree with this becouse HERE maps are only available on Lumia devices. But how to use HERE Launchers if we cannot publish it on the marketplace?

If somebody has had similar situation and know solution for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because it's better to use the ms-drive-to or ms-walk-to Uri scheme!
When you use those, the phone itself will launch HERE drive if it is present, otherwise Bing maps!

Get the needed example code and usage on MSDN here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj710324(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj710324%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to clearly state in your app description for Store and in the app itself, that it works only on Nokia devices. (Or you can implement some kind of fallback behavior for non-Nokia devices as well)
This way it should pass the certification, because the behavior will be expected and not confusing.

Comment: But, I think it is not possible to describe app to work only on Nokia devices. I have change it to use ms-drive-to Uri as Depechie told.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose either there were something wrong on the submission time, or the rules have changed. I at least submitted an application which is using the Uri Scheme directly, and it got accepted.

In the essense there is no requirements for any specific Application being installed, but there is a query made for applications which support the Uri scheme protocol. And if the HERE application having it is installed, then it will be launched.

And if there is no handlers available, then the market place should be opened for searching for the handlers. At least that's the way the system is designed for.